# Locating "Add Bluetooth Device" 's exe location

Tags: c#

I was keen on using the Process class [C#] to open "Add Bluetooth Device" wizard, but I was wondering what is the location of the wizard's exe?

I would be glad if someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Try using Process Explorer (free) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows 7, it's `C:\Windows\system32\DevicePairingWizard.exe`. Process Explorer says it was openeed with the following command line:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\DevicePairingWizard.exe" Provider\Microsoft.Devices.Bluetooth
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks mate, I didnt know this procedure could also be used to trace the file location, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do to execute any type of .exe from your code is to find the location of the .exe. This can be done it two way:

- You could run the .exe and while it is running open the Task Manager
  and go to the process that is affiliated with that .exe. The location
  of this .exe will be shown in the general tab of the properties of
  this process.
- Or, if that fails, you could simply Google it. For example, I
  searched 'add network device shortcut' and easily found the location
  of the .exe that you wanted. [How to Create a "Add a Device"
  Shortcut](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/111573-add-device-wizard-shortcut-create.html)

All you need to do after that, is put a 'Process.Start()' method.

> (MSDN Definition - Starts a process resource by specifying the name of
>   a document or application file and associates the resource with a new
>   Process component.)

```
private void buttonClick() {
        {
            Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\DevicePairingWizard.exe");                              
        }
    }
```

I know this answer is a bit late but I hope it helps anyone else that comes across this question looking for the same answer.

Comment: hey Paddy!  Welcome to SO! We try not to just give code-dump answers on SO. Could you edit your answer to add more "meat", explaining what you are doing and why this solve his problem? :) thank you

Comment: Hi @Julldar, very sorry. Hope this is better.

Comment: :) no apologies needed:) took me a LONG while to learn the proper format for answers and questions. I'm happy you're taking it well though :) Not all users take this kind of message the right way ^^ keep up the good work